# How to create a Liquidity pool for a token 2022 token

Tags: token-2022, liquiditypool

How would I go about creating a Liquidity pool for a token-2022 program token?

How does fluxbeam do it? Do they have their own custom program?

A general breakdown on what to Google and how to get to a point to where I can create something that allows users to place buy-sell orders also helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create Raydium AMM/openbook pools for token2022 tokens but you can create Raydium CLMM pools (as long as your token isn't using unsupported extensions as stated in the docs).

The process is a little more difficult than for AMM pool since you need to manually set liquidity price ranges. The Raydium docs explain it quite well.

Raydium Token 2022 docs:
https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/updates/token-2022-support

Raydium CLMM docs:
https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/liquidity-providers/providing-concentrated-liquidity-clmm/intro-on-concentrated-liquidity

Raydium CLMM pool creation docs:
https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/pool-creation/creating-a-clmm-pool-and-farm